# Define custom properties for x11 windows in order to associate additional data with them

Tags: c, x11, xcb

I'm trying to work out how to define my own window properties in xcb/x11, in order to be able to associate additional data with a window.

I can set and retrieve the pre-defined properties, such as XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, using xcb_change_property() and xcb_get_property(), just fine, but can't figure out how to define new properties of my own.

A number of tutorials allude to this being possible, and indeed integral to the design, but nowhere can I find any guidance on how to go about it.

Comment: Related question: [Assign user data to x11/xcb window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005771/assign-user-data-to-x11-xcb-window) but no clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about xcb but in X you can create an Atom (Property) with

[XInternAtom](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xinternatom)

> The XInternAtom function returns the atom identifier associated with the specified atom_name string. If only_if_exists is False, the atom is created if it does not exist.

and modify/retrieve it by

[XChangeProperty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xchangeproperty)
[XGetWindowProperty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xchangeproperty)

xcb should provide something similar.

Comment: Yup, `xcb_intern_atom` and `xcb_change_property`.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Why am i not surprised? Thank you very much!